# How to create a picture according to a grid table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, spring-mvc

Now I have some data to show in a grid table,now I want to show the data in a picture so that the other people can not get the data from the web,What tool can change a gird to a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is probably canvas.

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:20px'>" +
                  "<table border='1'><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>row 2, cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table>" +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes,but people can read the data from javascript code.And may be the picture is the best way.